# Plugin is available to update when its not

Tags: plugins

I have developed a plugin for my client, but for some reason, its saying that update is available.Whereas i have no idea how to feed a update. The plugin says in update field, about author with a different name (not me), its a totally confused situation. If someone hit update, my plugin can be overwritten by someone else. 
Why is it happening? 
How i make sure it is not updated by any other means, only if i have feed it to update.

Comment: Probably has the same name as a plugin on the repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress’ update checker is known to be quite greedy. To prevent these notices:

- use a unique name for your plugin
- use a unique directory name
- filter `http_request_args` and prevent your plugin from being checked ([example](https://github.com/cftp/external-update-api/blob/master/external-update-api/euapi.php))

Answer (score -1):

If you are not looking towards any future updates yourself, Put the plugin version number as 9999. This will prevent any update notices as 9999 is quite a bigger number for version.